# what does the @@ means in MSSQL when used in @@AnyExpression

Tags: sql-server

i want to know the meaning of @@ in MSSQL as i saw it in may forms like

```
 @@VERSION
   @@SERVERNAME
```

i just don't understand what @@ in any @@Expression stands for ?

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that the expression (function) is a (SQL Server) system function and their syntax usage follows the rules for all SQL Server functions.

In earlier versions of SQL Server they were called global variables. But they do not behave as variables. They are functions, as per SQL Server documentation.

Comment: those are not functions, but variables

Comment: No they are not. In earlier versions of SQL Server they were called variables (global). But they do not behave as variables. They are functions. Check the SQL Sever documentation about this.

Comment: :) - It's tough getting old, as I can attest.

Comment: Though in some contexts they do behave like variables. `Exec MySP @@VERSION` is valid syntax. This inline function call in the parameter list is not allowed for any other type of function.